# Parsing error for nested object?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can anyone help? My data is being filtered by values chosen from two dropdown lists - then nested/rolled up to get the mean value per day for these same values.  I am getting a "problem parsing d error" for the code below. Although both filter and nest functions are returning the correct data - the problem occurs when I try to apply this data to the line graph to update it?

```
    d3.select("#parameterType").on("change", function() 
    {   
    d3.select("#dateTimeTaken").on("change", function()
    {   
    var selectedParameter = document.getElementById("parameterType").value;
    var selectedMonth = document.getElementById("dateTimeTaken").value;

    //filter data by selected parameter and month    
    var selectedData = data.filter(function(d) { 
      return d.parameterType == selectedParameter  &&
      +d.dateTimeTaken.getMonth() == (selectedMonth - 1);});

    console.log(selectedData);//returning correct data

    //get average reading for each day within selected month 
    var newdata = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d3.time.day(d.dateTimeTaken);})    
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .rollup(function(d) 
        {
            return {
            mean: d3.mean(selectedData, function(d) {return +d.reading;})};
        })
    .entries(selectedData);
    console.log(newdata);//returning correct data

    //UPDATE GRAPH

    //not returning correct max values?     
    x.domain(d3.extent(newdata, function(d) { return d.key; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(newdata, function(d) { return d.values; })]);

    svg.select("path.line")
        .attr( "d", line(newdata));

    svg.select(".x.axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.select(".y.axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with the [line accessors](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_x). Can you update your code to include how you are initialising the `line` variable?

Comment: Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Majella/202df0a4a5a3ad20fb92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [code that you posted](https://gist.github.com/Majella/202df0a4a5a3ad20fb92), there are two problems which cause the said issue. Both the problems appear to stem from a misunderstanding of how data is nested and rolled up in D3.

## Explanation

```js
var newdata = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.dateTimeTaken;})    
    .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
    .entries(data);
```

This converts an object of the following kind:

```js
var data = [{
    parameterType: 'a',
    dateTimeTaken: '2013-01-01 12:00:00',
    reading: 100
}, {
    parameterType: 'a',
    dateTimeTaken: '2013-01-02 12:00:01',
    reading: 101
}];
```

to:

```js
[
    {
        "key": "2013-01-01 12:00:00",
        "values": [
            {
                "parameterType": "a",
                "dateTimeTaken": "2013-01-01 12:00:00",
                "reading": 100
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "2013-01-02 12:00:01",
        "values": [
            {
                "parameterType": "a",
                "dateTimeTaken": "2013-01-02 12:00:01",
                "reading": 101
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The `values` field is an array which accumulates the original data entries together.
[rollup](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-nest_rollup) then takes as argument the array which would have been `values`, calculates an aggregate metric from these (`mean` in your case) and *puts it in place of the array in the key `values`*.

Your `rollup` function:

```js
//AVERAGE READING FOR EACH DAY WITHIN SELECTED MONTH FOR SELECTED PARAMETER
// ...

 .rollup(function(d) {
    return {mean:d3.mean(selectedData, function(d) {return +d.reading;})};})
```

ignores the argument completely. I think it should read:

```js
 .rollup(function(d) {
    return {mean:d3.mean(d, function(d_) {return +d_.reading;})};})
```

Now the resulting array would like:

```js
[
    {
        "key": "2013-01-01 12:00:00",
        "values": {
            "mean": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "2013-01-02 12:00:01",
        "values": {
            "mean": 101
        }
    }
]
```

Note that the `values` key has yet another object inside it which contains the `mean`. You calculate the range for the `y` axis as:

```js
y.domain([0, d3.max(newdata, function(d) { return d.values; })]);
```

The reason why the maximum values are incorrect is because you are asking d3 to calculate the maximum over `objects` in `values`. The result of such an operation is ill defined. Instead, you should ask for maximum over `values.mean`:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(newdata, function(d) { return d.values.mean; })]);
```

This works and produces the correct result as shown in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XLNeP/

## Conclusion

That was about how to make the nesting and rollupus work correctly. Now to address a few other problems. Your `line` variable has the following accessors:

```js
var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.dateTimeTaken); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.reading); });
```

This works perfectly for the time you call:

```js
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(data));
```

However, `newdata` is of the form shown above, which has `key` and `values` at the top level and not `dateTimeTaken` or `reading`. Hence you would be better off using the `selectedData` which is just `data` filtered and preserves the data structure. However, if you want to draw a different line (e.g., with the `mean`) then you should define a new `d3.svg.line()` line generator with different accessors.

Comment: Thank you - you're a star!:)  I do need a line for the mean and that's what I'm having the difficulty with.  So I need to define a new line e.g var meanline = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) { return x(d.key); }).y(function(d) { return y(d.values.mean); }); - then to update  - svg.select("path.meanline").attr( "d", line(newdata));???

Comment: You probably mean `svg.select("path.meanline").attr( "d", meanline(newdata));` but, yes, that looks about correct.

Comment: Thanks:) Parsing error gone but for some reason only y axis updating.  Data is not being sorted using sortKeys and the x domain not returning the max value - does extent not work with a key value?  Updated gist:https://gist.github.com/Majella/202df0a4a5a3ad20fb92

Comment: [As per the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-nest_key), the value returned by the key is turned into string and since the default string format is not alphabetically sorted, you get seemingly unsorted x-axis and incorrect values for the time axis. Consider using `.toISOString()` in the `key` function since [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) can be alphabetically sorted. Then for `.extent`, parse it back to a date using the format `"%Y-%m-%bT%H:%M:%SZ"`.

Comment: Getting error message "Object 2013-03-01T14:03:58.000Z has no method 'getFullYear'" - think may be related to d3.time.day?

Comment: The conversion to ISO8601 happens correctly, but not parsing it back to a `Date` object. Are you using `d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ').parse` to parse the string back (esp. in the `.extent` function)?

Comment: That did the trick - I'd used your format from previous post "%Y-%m-%bT%H:%M:%SZ":)  Just one very last thing - I've defined the new line for the mean exactly as above but not displaying?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25921/discussion-between-musically-ut-and-newbie)